# Convert nvarchar to date time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have field called `event_datetime` in my table which is of data type `nvarchar`
(ex: `2017-04-25-12.09.14.36.089600`).
I need to convert it to date time.
Can any one please suggest how to do this?

Comment: ,Check your sample data.It is not in correct format.

Comment: The time part looks very strange.

Comment: Yep. I've no idea *what* datetime that string is meant to represent. There are too many groups for any conventional formats I'm aware of.

Comment: Try to take a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: I'm using 10.50.1600.1 version of SQL server.

Comment: Well, To extend on what Damien wrote - this is not a valid datetime string representation - and that is the sort of problems you will encounter when choosing the wrong data type. So the first thing to do is idenfity the invalid records, and the second thing is to query only the valid ones.

Comment: I'm using replace and stuff methods to convert the source to convertable format(2017/04/25 12:09:14). But it may increase load on server using that many functions. So, I want to know if there is any direct process to do this.

Comment: Is this 24 hours format?

Answer (score 1):

try Something like this if this helps but i am not sure if you still want the Microsecond part of it :

select CONVERT(datetime2, REPLACE(REPLACE(STUFF('2017-04-25-12.09.14.36',11,1,' '),'-',''),'.',':'))

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
DECLARE @S varchar(100) = '  2017-04-25-12.09.14.36.089600   '    
SELECT CAST(
            REPLACE(
                    STUFF(
                          LEFT(LTRIM(@S), 19)
                    , 11, 1, 'T')
            , '.', ':')
       as datetime) As ProperDataType -- just a hint :-)
```

Result:

```
ProperDataType
25.04.2017 12:09:14
```

[(live demo on rextester)](http://rextester.com/KFYZM54413)

Please note that I'm not testing for validity here - anything with a different format, or invalid numbers will raise an error - so if you had a value like this - `2017-14-25-12.09.14.36.089600` it will raise an error.

To do it properly you first need to identify the records that are convertible to dates - and to do that, the easy way is to use a cte and [`isdate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT REPLACE(
               STUFF(
                     LEFT(LTRIM(event_datetime), 19)
               , 11, 1, 'T')
      , '.', ':') As ProperlyFormatted
FROM YourTableName
)           

SELECT CAST(ProperlyFormatted as datetime) As event_datetime
FROM CTE
WHERE ISDATE(ProperlyFormatted) = 1
```

Note that I've used ISO8601 date format, so that you should always get the correct result regardless of your server local settins.